# extracting a specific word between : using sed, awk or grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file that has the following contents and many more.

```
#set_property board_part my.biz:ab0860_1cf:part0:1.0 [current_project]
 set_property board_part my.biz:ab0820_1ab:part0:1.0 [current_project]
```

My ideal output is as shown below (ie, the text after the first ":" and the second ":".

```
ab0820_1ab
```

I generally use python and use regular expression along the lines of below to get the result.

```
\s*set_property board_part trenz.biz:([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)
```

I wish to know how can it be done quickly and in a more generic way using commandline tools (sed, awk).

Comment: `awk -F':' '/set_property/{ print $2 }' `

Comment: Thanks @Inian, if the file contains many other contents it tends to write an empty line (Carriage Return) for all the remaining files. How can it be avoided ?

Comment: `awk -F':' '/set_property board_part/{ print $2 }` works

Comment: Output is one line only. Are the lines starting with `#` to be ignored?

Comment: `awk -F':' '/^[[:blank:]]*set_property board_part/{ print $2 }`  should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data has *my.biz* but your pattern tries to match *trenz.biz*

If `gnu awk` is available, you can use the capture group and then print the first value of  which is available in `a[1]`

```
awk 'match($0, /^\s*set_property board_part \w+\.biz:(\w+)/, a) {print a[1]}' file
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `set_property board_part`  Match literally
- `\w+\.biz:` Match 1+ word chars followed by `.biz` (note to escape the dot to match it literally)
- `(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word chars

Notes

- If you just want to match `trenz.biz` then you can replace `\w+\.biz` with `trenz\.biz`
- If the strings are not at the start of the string, you can change `^` for `\s` wo match a whitespace char instead

Output

```
ab0820_1ab
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use GNU `sed` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
#set_property board_part my.biz:ab0860_1cf:part0:1.0 [current_project]
 set_property board_part my.biz:ab0820_1ab:part0:1.0 [current_project]
garbage garbage garbage
```

then

```
sed -n '/ set_property board_part my.biz/ s/[^:]*:\([^:]*\):.*/\1/ p' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ab0820_1ab
```

Explanation: `-n` turns off default printing, `/ set_property board_part my.biz/` is so-called address, following commands will be applied solely to lines matching adress. First command is substitution (`s`) which use capturing group denoted by `\(` and `\)`, regular expression is as followes zero-or-more non-`:` (i.e. everything before 1st `:`), `:`, then zero-or-more non-`:` (i.e. everything between 1st and 2nd `:`) encased in capturing group `:` and zero-or-more any character (i.e. everything after 2nd `:`), this is replaced by content of 1st (and sole in this case) capturing group. After substitution takes place `p` command is issued to prompt GNU `sed` to print changed line.

(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)